# Составление схемы предложения

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

> Но вот липы кончились; я прошел мимо дома с террасой и мезонином, и передо мною неожиданно развернулся вид на барский двор и широкий пруд с купальней, с толпой зеленых ив, с деревней на том берегу, с высокой узкой колокольней, на которой горел крест, отражая в себе заходившее солнце.

Схема: `[...]; [...], и (...), с (...), с (...), с (...)`

Правильно ли составлена схема? Получается 6 предикативных частей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [...]; [...], и (...), с (...), с (...), с (...)
>
> получается 6 предикативных частей?

Четыре.

[...]; [...], и [...], (на которой...)

Но вот липы кончились; я прошел мимо дома с террасой и мезонином, и передо мною неожиданно развернулся вид на барский двор и широкий пруд с купальней, с толпой зеленых ив, с деревней на том берегу, с высокой узкой колокольней, на которой горел крест, отражая в себе заходившее солнце.

Comment: В текст вопроса Вы добавили запятую перед "на которой", а в ответе у Вас её нет.  Она-таки должна быть или не нужна?

Comment: Конечно, должна. Спасибо.